# NSManagedObject is there a way to import created subclass to xcdatamodel file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a question.

You can export an NSManagedObject subclass from xcode xcdatamodel file when you create an Entity.

Is there a way to import NSManagedObject subclass to the xcdatamodel diagram???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. However, it should be pretty easy to manual build the entity and you may find out that you had something missing (e.g. an inverse relationship).

You can import a compiled datamodel file (.mom) into a model design document (.xcdatamodel) using Xcode > Design > Data Model > Import.